# Column names don't appear when using AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Hy. I am trying to build a simple JTable using AbstractTableModel,but the column names don't appear even though I used a JScrollPane.

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
private String[] columnNames = new String[]{"#","Name","Price","Quantity","Description"};

public TableModel() {
    super();
    System.out.println("constructor");

}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return 0;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return 0;
}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return null;
}

public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    System.out.println("in");
    return columnNames[columnIndex];
}

}
```

I place the tabel on a JPanel in the following way:

```
table = new JTable(new TableModel());
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

The method getColumnName isn't invoked. Why?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your column count is zero, there is no need to get column names.

try

```
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}
```